# Trying to show expected wait is convex -- need to show an expression is positive

Tags: polynomials, convexity, queueing-theory

I need to show that the following expression is positive
$$ (B+1) (2 B+1) z_0^B-(B+2) (\rho +1) z_0-2 (B+1) (B-1) ((\rho +1) z_0-\rho )+(B-1) (\rho +1) > 0 $$

where $B\geq 1$ is an integer, $0<\rho<B$, and $z_0=z_0(\rho,B)$ is the unique root in $[0,1)$ of the polynomial  $z^{B+1}-(\rho+1)z+\rho$.

*Background:*

This expression comes from the second derivative wrt $\rho$ of the function

$$W(\rho)= \dfrac{1}{(1-z_0) \left(1+\rho -(B+1) z_0^B\right)}$$

which is the expected waiting time for a job to be processed when the is an arrival rate $\rho$ of higher priority jobs, service arrives at rate $1$, and each service arrival eliminates $B$ waiting jobs (or all of the waiting jobs if there are less than $B$).

We want to show that $W(\rho)$ is a convex function, and if we can show that the expression above is positive we have that the second derivative is positive.

Comment: Have you proved it for $B=1$, when some terms disappear, and $z_0$ is the root of a quadratic equation?

Comment: When $B=1$ the root is $z_0=\rho$ and the expression simplifies to $3\rho(1-\rho)>0$. the expected wait function $W(\rho)=\dfrac{1}{(1-\rho)^2}$ which is of course convex.